# AsyncTask: Not Writing data to file

Tags: java, android, file, android-asynctask

I'm fairly new to Android programming, I've been giving some code to solve a problem which I can't seem to figure out for quite a while now.

I've got a AsyncTask which is trying to save some data into a file placed on the internal storage of the device. The file is created but is populated with 0 bytes

```
public void exportFile(final Context mContext, boolean debug) {

    try {
        final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/DroidP";
        File dir = new File(path);
        dir.mkdirs();

        final File file = new File(dir, "Droid_export.txt");

        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();                          
        }

        file.createNewFile();

        final FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file,true);



        final int totalLines = recordsIdList.size();
        new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                try {



                    List<byte[]> mainBuffer = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

                    int i = 0;
                    int size = 0;

                    for (Integer r : recordsIdList) {
                        Log.i("test", db.getRecord(r).toExportSQL());

                        byte[] buffer = db.getRecord(r).toExportSQL().getBytes(); 
                        mainBuffer.add(buffer);
                        size += buffer.length;

                        publishProgress("Writing " + (i++) + " from "+ totalLines);
                    }

                    int pos = 0;
                    char[] outBuffer = new char[size];
                    for(byte[] chunk : mainBuffer) {
                        for(i=0;i<chunk.length;i++) {
                            outBuffer[pos] = (char)chunk[i];
                            pos++;
                        }                           
                    }

                    out.write(outBuffer);

                    out.flush();



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
      }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                progressDialog.setMessage(progress[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,
                        "Exporting file", "", true);
            }
        }.execute((Void) null);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

When I look at the logs, I'm able to see the data that I'm trying to save into the file, which is the correct one, but once the AsyncTask finishes a file is created with 0 bytes.Am I missing something? Remember, I'm fairly new to Android Programming.

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to read or to write the file?

Comment: I'm trying to write some SQL queries generated from other method into the file. Through LogCat I'm able to see the queries, but they aren't written into the file.

Comment: No you aren't - that may be what you *want* to do, but the code you have posted *reads* from a file.  It does not *write* to one.

Comment: Where do you close `out`? How do you call the AsyncTask?

Comment: @StenSoft  `out` is closed `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @Blackbelt updated the code to match the question. Already took note that you should not ask questions on stackoverflow if you're working. I posted the wrong method.

Comment: are you sure, you are starting the async task? I can't see any `.execute()`

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes the async task is being started, I can see the values I'm trying to insert in the file through LogCat. `.execute()` is not shown the above example, updating the question right away.

Comment: The question now contains the whole method, my bad for letting little pieces of code out of the question.

Comment: where are you checking the file's content?

Comment: @BlackBelt It was meant for debugging purposes, to see if the bytes were placed in the file.

Comment: I wasn't questioning your reasons. The broadcast is fired immediately after `execute() `. It is possible that you are trying to access the file while the AsyncTask is still writing it

Comment: @BlackBelt I'm sorry but instead of reading *when* I read *why* so my answer wasn't correct. I'm checking the files content through a android device through the file browser.

Comment: The reason why AsyncTask has the word "Async" in it hints at its nature - it's executed in another thread (a background thread). The fact that you start the media scanning process in another thread (aka the main thread) means there's the race condition. Try moving the media scanning code to `protected void onPostExecute(Void result)` and see if it helps. Actually you should also move all the code concerning `FileWriter out` to `doInBackground`, right now you are calling `out` Object from different threads without any synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested for your error but you could simplify your problem a bit by skipping the `byte` to `char` conversion and move file handing into the **async** task as many has suggested.

Try something like this:

```
private Boolean isExporting = false;

public void exportFile(final Context mContext, boolean debug) {
    if (!isExporting) {
        isExporting = true;
        new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                try {
                    // read data into byte array
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int i = 0;
                    for (Integer r : recordsIdList) {
                        byte[] buffer = db.getRecord(r).toExportSQL().getBytes();
                        Log.i("test", new String(buffer));
                        baos.write(buffer);
                        publishProgress("Writing " + (i++) + " from " + totalLines);
                    }
                    baos.close();
                    // write data to file
                    final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DroidP";
                    final File dir = new File(path);
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    final File file = new File(dir, "Droid_export.txt");
                    file.createNewFile();
                    final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
                progressDialog.setMessage(progress[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                isExporting = false;
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,
                        "Exporting file", "", true);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved! I'll award you the bounty once 14 hours have passed.